# If $u_n$ is bounded in $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, is $u_n^2$ bounded in the same space, too?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and let $X= H^1_0(\Omega)\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Let $(u_n)_n\subset X$ be a bounded sequence in $X$, i.e. $M>0$ exists such that $\|u_n\|_X\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

My question is: It is true that $u_n^2$ is bounded, too? I mean, does $\bar{M}$ exist such that $\|u_n^2\|_X\le \bar{M}$?

${\bf EDIT:}$ For any $u\in X$ it is
$$\|u\|_X = \|u\|_{H^1_0} + \|u\|_{\infty}.$$

If yes, could someone please help me  to prove it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You did not define $\|.\|_X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true: By the product/power rule for weak derivatives, we have $\nabla w^2=2w\nabla w$. Since $u_n\in L^\infty$ this formula applies and gives
$$
\|\nabla u_n^2\|_{L^2}\leq 2\| u_n\|_{L^\infty}\| \nabla u_n\|_{L^2},
$$
similarly,
$$
\| u_n^2\|_{L^2}\leq \| u_n\|_{L^\infty}\| u_n\|_{L^2}, \qquad \| u_n^2\|_{L^\infty}\leq \| u_n\|_{L^\infty}^2.
$$
Combining all this we get
$$
\| u_n^2\|_X \leq 2\| u_n\|_{L^\infty}\| u_n\|_X \leq 2\| u_n\|_X^2\leq 2M^2.
$$